# how to check if there is an entry for each day without gaps SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, date

I have a log table "*table1*" with values appended every day and need to find "*column3*" values and dates from "*column1*"​​, for which the data wasn't recorded. For example, my table looks like this:

| column1 | column2 | column3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-07-14 | 274,5 | markus |
| 2022-07-14 | 251,2 | tess |
| 2022-07-14 | 162,6 | mike |
| 2022-07-15 | 286,9 | markus |
| 2022-07-15 | 254,8 | tess |
| 2022-07-16 | 289,1 | markus |
| 2022-07-17 | 295,2 | markus |
| 2022-07-17 | 260,0 | tess |
| 2022-07-17 | 182,3 | mike |

Everything is ok with `column3 = 'markus'`, but I need to get something like this as output:

| column1 | column3 |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-07-15 | mike |
| 2022-07-16 | tess |
| 2022-07-16 | mike |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way of addressing this problem is by:

- rebuilding all combinations of names and dates
- left-joining this table with your original tables
- filtering on records whose table values is null

```
WITH cte_dates AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT column1 AS "date" FROM tab
), cte_names AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT column3 AS "name" FROM tab
)
SELECT cte_dates.date,
       cte_names.name
FROM       cte_dates
CROSS JOIN cte_names
LEFT JOIN tab
       ON cte_dates.date = tab.column1
      AND cte_names.name = tab.column3
WHERE tab.column2 IS NULL
```

**Output**:

| date | name |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-07-16T00:00:00.000Z | mike |
| 2022-07-16T00:00:00.000Z | tess |
| 2022-07-15T00:00:00.000Z | mike |

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2jitEqeA5dZp28zLiqma3K/0).

---

If gaps can be found among your dates, you need to use [generate_series](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html) with boundary dates to generate the corresponding calendar in the first cte:

```
WITH cte_dates AS (
    SELECT "date"
    FROM (SELECT MIN(column1) AS startdt, 
                 MAX(column1) AS enddt 
          FROM tab) boundaries
    CROSS JOIN generate_series( startdt :: timestamp 
                              , enddt   :: timestamp
                              , '1 day' :: interval ) "date"
),
...
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2jitEqeA5dZp28zLiqma3K/1).

Answer (score 1):

At first, you must build a time base for the whole period, then cross-join it with distinct of column3 to create all possibilities, then subtract it from your base data as follows:

```
with cross_sql as (select * from 
(SELECT timebase 
FROM   generate_series(timestamp '2022-07-14'
                     , timestamp '2022-07-17'
                     , interval  '1 day') as timebase) A
cross join                   
(select distinct column3 from table1) B )

select column3, timebase from cross_sql 
except
select column3, column1 from table1;
```